# Class-based projection with native query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, projection, nativequery

Is it impossible to use class-based projection in Spring Data repository with native query?
And how?

PS: I tried to use `@Query(value = "select new package.Foo(id, name) from my_table, nativeQuery = true)` but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Need to use `@SqlResultSetMapping`, `ConstructorResult` and `NamedNativeQuery`.